# AngularJS constant is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to set up some validation in Angular Formly forms. Below is a snippet of my code. When I run the app, I get an unknown [provider error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n).

```
var genericFormApp = angular.module('genericFormApp', ['formly', 'formlyMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'angular.filter', 'ngSanitize', 'angularLazyImg', 'angular-slideout']);

var conf = {
    validation: {
        stringMessages: {
            required: "Required.",
            email: "Must be a valid email address.",
            // generic
            valid: "Must be a valid value.",
        },
        toMessages: [
          {
              name: "valid",
              prop: "datepicker",
              prefix: "",
              postfix: "",
              defaultMessage: "Must be a valid date."
          }
        ],
    }
};

genericFormApp.constant("conf", conf);


genericFormApp.run(function (formlyConfig, formlyValidationMessages, conf) {
    // set types here
        var i, k, str = conf.validation.stringMessages, to, toMess = conf.validation.toMessages;
    // generic messages
    for (i in str) {
        formlyValidationMessages.addStringMessage(i, str[i]);
    }
    // template option messages, to optionally override
    for (i in toMess) {
        to = toMess[i];
        formlyValidationMessages.addTemplateOptionValueMessage(to.name, to.prop, to.prefix, to.postfix, to.defaultMessage);
    }

});
```

If I change the run function to this:
`genericFormApp.run(function (formlyConfig, formlyValidationMessages, conf) 
{}`
the app runs.

Now if I try to access conf, I get the unknown provider error:
`genericFormApp.run(function (formlyConfig, formlyValidationMessages, conf) 
{console.log(conf)}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is working

```
genericFormApp.constant('conf', (function () {
                var conf = {
                    validation: {
                        stringMessages: {
                            required: "Required.",
                            email: "Must be a valid email address.",
                            // generic
                            valid: "Must be a valid value."
                        },
                        toMessages: [
                            {
                                name: "valid",
                                prop: "datepicker",
                                prefix: "",
                                postfix: "",
                                defaultMessage: "Must be a valid date."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                };
                return conf;
            })())
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that (as I'm using Visual Studio), the minification that occurs, causes the run function to no run. I had to inject the names:

```
genericFormApp.run(['formlyConfig', 'formlyValidationMessages', 'conf', function(formlyConfig, formlyValidationMessages, conf) {

    // set types here
        var i, k, str = conf.validation.stringMessages, to, toMess = conf.validation.toMessages;
    // generic messages
    for (i in str) {
        formlyValidationMessages.addStringMessage(i, str[i]);
    }
    // template option messages, to optionally override
    for (i in toMess) {
        to = toMess[i];
        formlyValidationMessages.addTemplateOptionValueMessage(to.name, to.prop, to.prefix, to.postfix, to.defaultMessage);
    }

}]);
```